# Ansible cant parse kubectl patch command

Tags: ansible

I am trying to execute below kubectl patch command using ansible but it gives error "We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML".

I also tried adding escape characters before single and double quotes but no luck.

my task:

```
- name: Patching cnx-ingress to use loadbalancer provate ip as ingress. 

  shell: kubectl patch svc cnx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller -n connections -p '{"spec": {"type": "LoadBalancer", "externalIPs":["172.26.0.13"]}}'   
  become_user: "{{ __sudo_user }}"
```

Error:

```
TASK [component-pack : Setup Community Ingress Controller] ********************************************************************************
fatal: [master1.internal.dev.net]: FAILED! => {"reason": "We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:\nJSON: No JSON object could be decoded\n\nSyntax Error while loading YAML.
\n  mapping values are not allowed here\n\nThe error appears to be in '/Users/ujjawalkhare/connections3/deployment-ansible/ansible/roles/hcl/component/tasks/setup_community_ingress.yml': line 207, column 111, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n- 
name:                      Patching cnx-ingress to use loadbalancer provate ip as ingress\n  
shell:                     kubectl patch svc cnx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller -n connections -p '{\"spec\": {\"type\": \"LoadBalancer\", \"externalIPs\":[\"172.26.0.13\"]}}'\n 
                                                                                                     ^ here\nWe could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with\nunbalanced quotes. If starting a value with a quote, make sure the\nline ends with the same set of quotes. For instance this arbitrary\nexample:\n\n    foo: \"bad\" \"wolf\"\n\nCould be written as:\n\n    foo: '\"bad\" \"wolf\"'\n"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the entire argument to `shell` (because it contains characters that make a YAML parser think you're trying to start a mapping value). Because you're already using both single- and double-quotes in the script, your best bet is to make use of one of YAML's block-quote operators. Perhaps:

```
    - name: Patching cnx-ingress to use loadbalancer provate ip as ingress.
      shell: >
        kubectl patch svc cnx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller
        -n connections
        -p '{"spec": {"type": "LoadBalancer", "externalIPs":["172.26.0.13"]}}'
      become_user: "{{ __sudo_user }}"
```

Also, consider the Ansible [k8s module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/kubernetes/core/k8s_module.html#ansible-collections-kubernetes-core-k8s-module) instead of running `kubectl patch`.

Comment: thanks, i dint know this, it worked like charm